# iOS View Hierarchy for setting up Auto Layout Constraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

What is the closest ancestor to `self.navigationController.navigationBar` and a subview of `self.view` in a view controller so I can add the constraint to that ancestor?

```
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[self.searchBar setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addSubview:self.searchBar];

NSLayoutConstraint* cn = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.searchBar  
attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
toItem:self.navigationController.navigationBar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom 
multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
```

I tried doing

```
[self.view addConstraint:cn];
[self.navigationController.view addConstraint:cn];
```

but both times I get the error, "Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal."

Can someone explain the view hierarchy of a view controller in relation to the navigationController?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't make a constraint between the top of your view and the top of the search bar? The top of your view should be at the bottom of the navigation bar, so that should give you what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view tree looks like this:

[image]

So, navigationController.view is the closest ancestor of the navigation bar and your view. I'm not sure why that didn't work. Where did you put that code?

Comment: I think the suggestion in your comment is probably the way to go here. The search bar should just be pinned to the top of its superview.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up going with your suggestion in the comment above, that worked well

Comment: @rdelmar Hi, but how Can I make it work if the NavigationBar is translucent ? In that case Adding this constraint to self.view will hide the search bar under the Navigation Bar right ?